# Dynamically filling a list with 9 elements from datomic db

Tags: list, clojure, datomic

So I have something like this method:

```
(defn get-nine-posts []  
  (let [nine-tile ()]
   (->>
      ;;gets three posts
     (conj nine-tile (->> (get-a-bunch-of-posts)
                          (take 3)))

      ;;maybe gets three posts.. [gets somewhere between 0 and 3]
     (conj nine-tile (get-maybe-three-posts))

      ;;fill the rest of the nine-tile
     (conj nine-tile (->>  (get-posts-with-some-args 75 17)
                           (take (- 9 (count nine-tile)))) ;; $$$
     (flatten))))
```

It jams three lists together.  The last list I want to add should fill up the remaining number of slots (there are 9).

But something like

```
 (count nine-tile)  ;; $$$
```

in the middle of the last conj simply returns 0.  I would expect it to be able to evaluate how many elements are in the list already.  I'd like to (take) the difference.

What's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: the nine-tile in (count nine-tile) refers to nine-tile in (let [nine-tile ()]

Comment: `(conj nine-tile)` does not alter the list referenced by `nine-tile` - it returns a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(->> (concat (take 3 (get-a-bunch-of-posts))
             (get-maybe-three-posts)
             (get-posts-with-some-args 75 17))
     (take 9))
```

Comment: thanks, not at all what i was expecting but just as effective! (=